# Find maximum degree of divisibility given list of number

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function that find degree of divisibility of a list of number.

Example given list : [2,4,8,2]

- 2 is divisible by [2,2] so its degree of divisibility is 2
- 4 is divisible by [2,4,2] so its degree of divisibility is 3
- 8 is divisible by [2,4,8,2] so its degree of divisibility is 4
- 2 is divisible by [2,2] so its degree of visibility is 2 as in the first case

So the result of maximum divisibility here is 4.
I tried doing this but it return 8 instead of 4

```
    def find_most_divisors(input_list):
        test_list=[]

        for i in input_list:
            c=0
            for n in range (1,i+1):
                if i%n==0:
                   c+=1
            test_list.append(c)
        return input_list[test_list.index(max(test_list))]

    x = [2,4,8,2]
    print (find_most_divisors(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your return statement to `max(test_list)`, and it should work!

Answer (score 1):

You can change your return statement to `max(test_list)`.
like this: `return max(test_list)`

The whole code:

```
def find_most_divisors(input_list):
        test_list=[]
        for i in input_list:
            c=0
            for n in range (1,i+1):
                if i%n==0:
                   c+=1
            test_list.append(c)
        return max(test_list)

x = [2,4,8,2]
print (find_most_divisors(x))
```

Reason: `input_list[test_list.index(max(test_list))]` -> `input_list[test_list.index(4)]` -> `input_list[2]` -> `8`